# xargs cat a file with aws cli (amazon s3 move)

Tags: linux, command-line, xargs, aws, amazon-s3

I have a file called `file.csv`, which is a list of the files (or more precisely, file paths path in an S3 Bucket) that need to be moved to another folder in s3.

This file lists 53,00,000 files.  I have tried the following, but each move is taking a long time.

```bash
cat file.csv | xargs -I {} aws s3 mv s3://Bucket1/{} s3://Bucket2/{}
```

I am trying to speed up the process with the following:

```bash
cat file.csv | xargs -P50 -I {} aws s3 mv --recursive s3://Bucket1/{} s3://Bucket2/{}
```

...but it doesn't seem to be working.

I also tried:

```bash
while read line; do
  echo ${line} | \
    xargs -n1 -P100 -I {} \
      aws s3 mv s3://Bucket1/{} s3://Bucket2/{} --recursive
done < file.csv
```

But that doesn't seem to work either.

How can I  run multiple aws cli commands with `xargs` by reading the input file?

Comment: while read line
do
echo ${line} | xargs -n1 -P100 -I {} aws s3 mv s3://Bucket1/{} s3://Bucket2/{} --recursive
done < file.csv    -  trried this as well , not working

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of the lines in `file.csv'?

Comment: There is a similar question with a good answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408222/376937)

Comment: Hanu, put `echo` in front of your `aws` command so that you can see what `xargs` wants to do. Does this help clarify why "_it doesn't seem to be working_"?

Comment: Thanks Chris. echo helped out. working after removing the --recursive